# CakePHP doesn't unescape "+" to " " in a URL

Tags: url, cakephp, escaping

I'm developing a CakePHP application which uses the standard CakePHP URL schema.

If I use the following function in a Controller:

```
class IndexController extends AppController {
    public $uses = false;
    public function test($a) {
        var_dump($a);
    }
}
```

And call it with this URL:

```
http://server/index/test/Hello+%2BTest
```

I get this result:

```
string(11) "Hello++Test"
```

I would expect the first "+" to be unescaped to " ". Why doesn't this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean "unencode" instead of "unescape".

This is happening probably because the + sign is a valid character for a URL.  Only the urlencoded characters (i.e. %xx) will be converted back to "readable" characters. (though pretty sure this is done by Apache, not cake)

If you want to force conversion, you can just run it through PHP's [urldecode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) function.

From [RFC 1738](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html) :

> Thus, only alphanumerics, the special characters "$-_.+!*'(),", and reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used unencoded within a URL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you said the + sign is a valid character in the URL so the error was on the client side where the space was encoded wrongly. (I couldn't use `urldecode()` because that would decode both plus signs to spaces)